# Encoding issue - Win Xp vs Win 2003 

Tags: .net, windows, encoding, internationalization

There are 2 machines, one with Xp one with Win 2003. Both are Japanese versions!

If you get the available encodings (via Regional Settings or programatically, Encoding.GetEncodings() ) this happens:

1. on Xp, the resulting list is in Latin characters
2. on Win 2003, the list is in Japanese characters

Some guy at work though to persist the encoding based on its name not on its code and now I have to investigate Japanese machines :)

Do you know of a way to force Win XP (not 2003) to give the list of encodings in Japanese (remember, the Xp is the Japanese version) ?

Comment: This happens when .NET is missing the Japanese language pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the answer to the actual problem, but I think the best way to handle this is to migrate to code page instead of display name.

Also, one can detect when a mismatch occurs and force a certain language for their encoding - ex: Japanese. Good thing they all include English as well.

To get a little more fancy, you can have a config file to store the code page.